# SQL server convert datetime using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the query I need in SQL server but I'm using Entity Framework and would like the same results using LINQ. Here is the SQL:

```
select convert(varchar, date_recorded, 12), MAX(outdoor_temp), MAX(wind_speed)
from weatherdata
group by convert(varchar, date_recorded, 12)
order by convert(varchar, date_recorded, 12) DESC ;
```

This converts my datetime column to a correct format that allows me to group properly. Basically I need to be able to convert my SQL datetime to yymmdd format.

Many thanks

Comment: Your `date_recorded` column is actually some sort of date-time, and you're attempting to group it by _day_ (remove time information), right?  I dislike converting dates to character data on principle, but I don't think SQL Server has just a plain 'date' type (which is actually more representative, but...).  Since you're ditching the index anyways, I'd try doing something like getting the difference in days between 0001-01-01 and the column.  Especially because that format isn't going to sort/group like you expect (only a 2-digit year?).

Comment: I think I'll re create the database as SQL Server does have a date data type which I should of used from the start!

Comment: Well, hold on, do you only want dates, or would it be better to actually store timestamps?  Store the best fit for the data.  If you want to group it by date, then convert it to date for your grouping (there are optimizations available, but I'd start with 'correct' behavior).

Comment: If you just want to remove the time component, then why don't you try casting `date_recorded` as a `DATE` type, which has only the date component. Eg:
`SELECT CAST(date_recorded AS DATE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var entries = new List<Entry>()
                {
                    {new Entry { Date = DateTime.UtcNow, Outdoor_Temp = 10, Wind_Speed = 5 }},
                    {new Entry { Date = DateTime.UtcNow, Outdoor_Temp = 5, Wind_Speed = 10}},
                    {new Entry { Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1), Outdoor_Temp = 15, Wind_Speed = 7}}
                };

            (from e in entries 
             group e by e.Date.ToShortDateString() into g
             select 
                new 
                {
                    StringDate = g.Key,
                    MaxWind_Speed = g.Max(entry => entry.Wind_Speed),
                    MaxOutdoor_Temp = g.Max(entry => entry.Outdoor_Temp)
                }
             ).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        }

        public class Entry
        {
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public int Outdoor_Temp { get; set; }
            public int Wind_Speed { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Date : {0}, Outdoor_Temp : {1}, Wind_Speed : {2}", Date, Outdoor_Temp, Wind_Speed);
            }
        }
    }
```